# AppEngine: can't find import "google.golang.org/appengine"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy an API on AppEngine but I'm not sure why it's not working, here's an extract of the code:

```
package main 

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"

    "google.golang.org/appengine"
)


func main () {
    InitPubSub()

    http.HandleFunc("/", HandlerBase)
    http.HandleFunc("/user", HandlerUser)
    http.HandleFunc("/event", HandlerEvent)

    appengine.Main()
}
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to deploy the app (gcloud app deploy): **main.go:9: can't find import: "google.golang.org/appengine"**

I've followed the installation guide: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/download

And downloaded the appengine package: go get google.golang.org/appengine

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from the Google App Engine forum:

"Developers are aware of this issue and are actively contributing towards a solid solution to it. In the meanwhile, you should be able to use "goapp deploy" instead of the gcloud command."

Comment: `goapp deploy -application [YOUR_PROJECT_ID] -version [YOUR_VERSION_ID] [YOUR_APP_DIR]`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too when I was following: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/tools/using-local-server

What worked for me was replacing

`import "google.golang.org/appengine"`

with:

`import "appengine"`

I'm not sure if the instruction is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

To run a go appengine project, I found this project structure for a single service more than enough.

```
your/project/path/src/mainapp.go
your/project/path/src/app.yaml
or
your/project/path/src/mainfolder/mainapp.go
your/project/path/src/mainfolder/app.yaml
your/project/path/src/lib/lib1/watever.go
your/project/path/src/lib/lib2/whatever2.go
your/project/path/src/google.golang.org/ - for the golang appengine package
your/project/path/src/golang.org/ - golang packages
your/project/path/src/github.org/ - github packages
```

The subfolders/package folders, must not be above the main app.yaml file. Furthermore, the golang appengine package must be placed right inside "src/" and can only be imported directly from the "google.golang.org" import path and below that, not above. i.e. "customFolder/google.golang.org" is not allowed, "appengine", is however, allowed, provided that the app.yaml file is directly under src folder : src/app.yaml - src/mainapp.go.